# how to re-load a JavaScript page with re-displaying it

Tags: javascript, html, vxworks

I need to read a page from the server to get the data of an element that the server will dynamically change.

I don't want to re-display the entire page -- I just want to read from the server just the single element that changed, and only re-display that single element.

This is because it is a vxworks server page and the single element will be a dynamically chaning windmark (vxworks's method of exposing vxworks data to a web page).

Comment: You can't. You'll need to use AJAX to go fetch the data and use customized JavaScript to update the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never worked with vxworks, but I think an Ajax request will also do it in this case.
With Ajax you are able to load specific elements of your site asynchron. This means the whole site doesn't reload, only the element.
Normally I use the JQuery framwork for this, as it easier to use.
For more information check it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I got the answer from: http://api.jquery.com/load/
which I got originally from this page, but it seems someone changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the jQuery library and make an ajax request to fetch the data.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('/your/server/path/of/the/data, function(data) {
        // do sth. with the data, e.g. insert the data into your element.
        $("#elem").html(data);
    });
})
</script>
```

Your HTML should include an element whose id is "elem" to display the data.

For more information about jQuery, visit http://jquery.com/.